Back button functionality from subview
I am just starting with SwiftUI. I have added a custom back button in one of my detail page in a subview like following:
    struct ListingHeaderView: View {
    let listing: Listing
    let offset: Double
    @State var backButtonClick: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            ListingImageCarousalView(listing: listing)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400 + (offset > 0 ? offset : 0))
                .offset(y: (offset > 0 ? -offset : 0))
            Button {
                backButtonClick = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    .background {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.white)
                            .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    }
                    .padding(40)
            }
        }
    }
}

Now I want to perform back button action on click of this button. I have already setup a state variable to track the back button click and added this variable in ViewModel. The above view is used in my main view as following:
@StateObject var viewModel = ExploreViewModel(service: ExploreService())
        ScrollView {
                        SearchAndFilterBar(location: $viewModel.searchLocations)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                                    showDestinationSearchView.toggle()
                                }
                            }
    }

